# Определение кодовой страницы текста

Tags: golang, utf-8, текст, codepage, utf16le

Хочу посоветоваться. Может я чего не нашёл... хоть честно искал

**Подскажите доступное на golang решение по определению кодировки текстовых данных?**

В процессе написания утилиты потребовалось определять кодовую страницу в которой записан текстовый файл.
В итоге захотел унифицировать и соответственно определять все самые популярные (возможные) кодировки для русского языка.

Из готовых решений нашёл для golang:
1. из стандартной библиотеки html/charset функция DetermineEncoding()
2. вторая saintfish/chardet на [github](https://github.com/saintfish/chardet)
Обе уверенно ошибаются на некоторых файлах. Стандартная та вообще почти ничего определить не может по текстовым файлам, оно и понятно, её для html страниц делали.

Ещё есть обёртка над iconv - некое решение вроде живущее в linux, но запустить её я не смог, компилить сишный код это пока не по мне... соответственно проверить качество тоже не могу

Свою уже сделал, но прежде чем выкладывать хочу убедиться в интересности велосипеда.

Comment: Не думаю, что задачу детектирования кодировки можно решить на 100%.  Лучше заставьте клиента указывать кодировку явно.  А ещё лучше — принимать только _UTF-8._

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что 100% решения быть не может.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что 100% решения быть не может. Клиента нет. Принимать только UTF-8 невозможно, речь идёт об архивных файлах. Мне не хочется делать совсем подделку если есть работающий вариант, пусть на 95%.хотя сейчас у меня кроме специально сформирован ногой файла - ответ 100%. Но это я ещё мало тестов написал.  Надеюсь 99% у меня получится. Вот собираюсь ковырять Akelpad исходники. Он тоже умеет определять кодировки, пока всегда успешно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выложил на [github](https://github.com/softlandia/cpd) свою версию определения кодировки
Пример использования

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/softlandia/cpd"
)
func main() {
    t, _ := cpd.FileCodePageDetect(os.Args[1])
    fmt.Printf("file detected as:\t%s\n", t)
}
```

Буду доделывать, особенно если понравится, впрочем всё равно буду доделывать.
Если соберусь с духом напишу в Хабр